# is it ever allowed (or trappable) to pass an undefined variable into a python function?

Tags: python

I'm looking for the behavior where a function can accept an arbitrary and possibly undefined variable as an argument.  If the variable passed in actually exists, do something.  If that variable does not exist (i.e. is undefined), do something else.

I can implement this by wrapping the function call that uses the possibly undefined variable in a try/except block to catch a NameError, but what I really want is to do this INSIDE the function itself, rather than having to wrap every time I call the function.

Is this even a thing in Python?

```
def func(foo, bar):
    print(f"I like {foo} and {bar}")

def func2(foo, bar):
    try:
        print(f"I like {foo} and {bar}")
    except NameError:
        print(f"I like {foo} and I just made up a value for -- {whatever was passed} --")

a = 'Mike'
```

Ideally, if a user called the function like this:   `func2(a, purple['people'].eaters)` the output would be:

`I like mike and I just made up a value for  -- self.purple['people'].eaters --`

Comment: Are you looking for `None`? For ex: `func(None, None)`, if so you can check with `if(foo == None)`

Comment: Not possible in Python. That kind of thing requires a language with a fundamentally different evaluation strategy, like R.

Comment: This sounds like an xy problem

Comment: `None` doesn't help me here, I specifically needed to trap undefined things.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in python because the arguments are evaluated by the caller not the function being called, so the exception can't be caught inside the function.

One way of doing this would be to pass in a string, which would then be evaluated by the function, like this:

```
def func2(foo, bar):
    try:
        print(f"I like {foo} and {eval(bar)}")
    except NameError:
        print(f"I like {foo} and I just made up a value for -- {bar} --")

func2(a, "purple['people'].eaters")
```

Comment: This evaluates the input expression in the wrong environment. The expression needs to be evaluated with the caller's local and global namespaces, not `func2`'s. (Also, even if you adjust the `eval` call using something like `inspect` to access the caller's scope, closure variables won't work right, which is particularly inconvenient for comprehensions.)

Comment: Yeah, I had considered that possibility but it has drawbacks I'm not crazy about.